# Execute SQL stored in dataframe using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a list of SQL's stored in a hive table column, I have to get one sql at a time from the hive table and execute the SQL, I'm getting the SQL as a dataframe, but can anyone tell me how to execute the SQL stored as a dataframe?

```
The column parameter_value contains the SQL



  extrac_sql = spark.sql(""" select parameter_value 
                        from schema_name.table_params 
                        where project_name = 'some_projectname'
                        and sub_project_name = 'some_sub_project'
                        and parameter_name = 'extract_sql' """)
```

now the extract_sql contains the sql, how to execute it?

Comment: `extrac_sql.show()` returns the first 20 rows by default. If your dataset isn't large and you can pull it all one time in memory, write `extrac_sql.collect()` to get all the rows.

Comment: @user7343922 Please let me know if the following answer helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
sqls = spark.sql(""" select parameter_value 
                        from schema_name.table_params 
                        where project_name = 'some_projectname'
                        and sub_project_name = 'some_sub_project'
                        and parameter_name = 'extract_sql' """).collect()

for sql in sqls:
    spark.sql(sql[0]).show()
```